# Returning every other element of a list in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm trying to return ever second element within a list, for example [1;2;3;4] would return [2;4] and it works for any type of list, but I'm really struggling to make this work and I'm unsure why it won't work, can someone help me?

```
let rec everyEven a = function
|[]->[]
|x::y::t -> y::everyEven t
```

Comment: So what is the purpose of the `a` parameter? What happens with a single item list?  You pretty much have it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [OCaml - return a list containing all the elements in even position in the input list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269126/ocaml-return-a-list-containing-all-the-elements-in-even-position-in-the-input)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let us test your ocaml script (for example, using the toplevel):

> Error: This expression has type 'a list -> 'a list but an expression was expected of type 'a list

where `everyEven t` is underlined to indicate where the problem is. Now it is time to **trust the types** as you should always do in functional programming.

The error says you that `everyEven t` wants a generic list to produce a generic list. That means that `everyEven` (w/o `t`) expects, in general, **two** arguments (rather than one as you thought). That's because you are using the `function` keyword which is a built-in pattern matching on an anonymous argument. Let us then specify the pattern match on the argument `a`:

```
let rec everyEven a =
match a with
|[]->[]
|x::y::t -> y::everyEven t ;;
```

The result is that the code is accepted, but a warning is raised:

> Warning 8: this pattern-matching is not exhaustive. Here is an example of a value that is not matched: _::[]

meaning that we should also provide the case of one-element list:

```
let rec everyEven a =
match a with
|[]-> []
|[_] -> []
|x::y::t -> y::everyEven t ;;
```

That's it!
Some run tests:

```
everyEven [1;2;3;4] ;;
```

> `[2;4]`.

While `everyEven [1;2;3];;` returns `[2]`, and `everyEven [1];;` returns `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use `a` only to match on it, the `function` construct is appropriate.  Here is how (also grouping the cases with the same outcome):

```
let rec everyEven = function
  | [] | [_] -> []
  | _::y::t -> y::everyEven t
```